# How to prevent simulated mouse events in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, browser, touch

Mobile browsers simulate mouse events in order to support websites that only attach handlers to mouse events. However, if you want to implement two interaction models - one for mouse events, and one for touch events - then it's helpful to prevent the browser from simulating mouse events.

On iOS Safari this is fairly straightforward - simply run preventDefault on touchend:

```
jQuery(document).on('touchend', function(e) {
  // Do some logic      
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

That's pretty sane. Unfortunately, neither Android's default browser nor Dolfin cancel mouse simulation using this technique. (Dolfin will cancel mousedown when preventDefault is run on touchstart - but that's not very helpful, because you don't know what action the finger will take on touchstart.)

Is there some other way of conditionally, or even not conditionally, preventing simulated mouse events from firing?

[EDIT]

In order to begin to understand the problem(s) better, I've started a touch events compatibility table at: http://labs.cruncher.ch/touch-events-compatibility-table/

Comment: Also, comments from experience with mobile Chrome or FF greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you detect if it's a mobile browser or not before attaching the mouse events?

Comment: @JaredFarrish The methods for mobile browser detection are never 100% accurate.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Well, generally, no. The best way to do that would be to listen for the first touch event. By the time that comes in, though, you'll have wanted to initialise your application already. (AND - we better be careful not to confuse 'Mobile browser' with 'Touch interface' because we don't know what kind of devices are coming next)

Comment: Ok. That's annoying it's not been managed in a more clear-cut manner.

Comment: Can you ask your users first which they want? (Something like the old Flash/HTML picker.) Not saying this is a great idea, but if it's causing problems, maybe it could be a useful.

Comment: Also, could you use a dispatch model instead, in which the matching touch and mouse events both fire another function, with one canceling the other? So they essentially point to another function, but use `.call()` or `.apply()` to handle scope?

Answer (score 3):

While there are some crafty ways to achieve this, there are two common practices that I use to get around this discrepancy:

**1) Use flags**

Setting boolean flags in your event handlers, such as `mouseIsDown` or `mouseIsMoving`, can be  set and checked for mouse and touch events. If a user clicks a mouse, accept that as a mouse event. Then, if a touch event occurs along with it, disregard it.

**2) Implement only what's necessary**

Well, this is good practice anyway. Don't bother adding `touchmove` and `mousemove` events if you don't need to. It will just make it harder to maintain the code. Edit: Probably should have been more specific: consider rethinking your UI if you need more advanced event tracking.

Lastly, don't rely on external hardware configuration lists, as these are rarely 'completely' accurate.

Comment: Is your first suggestion saying essentially `$(document.body).mousemove()`, which would set a global flag, then be removed, and that would be used in each `mouse-` event to detect the presence of a mouse?

Comment: 1) The problem with simulated events is the touch events fire first, then the mouse events - so by the time the mouse event comes along, the touch event is already finished. Secondly, storing state like this can get pretty hairy (depending what you're doing) when dealing with multiple touches. I try not to store state whenever possible. Thirdly, I want to deal with code that is already written to use mouse events - I don't want to go into all those handlers and insert code that conditionally asks if we're in a touch interface. I appreciate your answer, though!

Comment: Also, I think your second is not really another approach, it's just good practice. Your real answer is the first one, with the second being a reminder to think carefully about what you really need (always good advice).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes. A `mousedown` or `touchstart` would set a flag, and `mouseup` or `touchend` would finish it. The second point is indeed just a practice, but an overlooked and important one, at least for me. If you're making a universal webapp, don't expect everyone to have advanced gesture events; just go with the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @stephband 1) I've found that well implemented flags can bypass this problem in most cases. 2) It is dependent, but you shouldn't need more than two flags for most cases. 3) The idea is that the listener could set a flag and call a generic `onMouseMove` function or similar, and the touch events would not intervene (or vice versa). But, I will respect your decision. Still, there really aren't any good alternatives out there that don't use a lot of code and are at least equally as hairy!

Comment: @JeffreySweeney Cheers. You may be right that it's the only viable approach. In which case your last sentence answers the question - in essence, 'you can't'.

Comment: @stephband Touchevent standards are still fairly young. Give it a decade or two ;)

Comment: @stephband, Jeffrey - This won't get muddled *at all* as more and more concurrent touch and mouse/alternative device systems get implemented *at the same time*. This may be the case already, but I wonder if Windows 8 will allow concurrent touch and mouse interaction?